# React- Router vs Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am fairly new to the web development and I am still learning. 
I am trying to build a back end for my web application. I am currently using react with redux for my front end. My question is, in order to create a back end do I need to use the react-router or do I have to use a completely different platform like Node.js. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Please, try to understand what Redux, React, Node, and Redux-Router is. You can build backend only using node, from your list. I recommend to look at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app or https://nextjs.org/

Comment: React, redux and react-router are on the client side. For the backend you will need, Node and Express and MongoDB for example. React-router is needed by React to provide navigation, i. e. to pass from one client page to another in a Single Page Application. My advice for you, is to focus on the client side (React and react router) for now, it is tough enough!

Answer (score 3):

In order to create a backend, you will need to build a server-side application using Node, .NET Core, Java, PHP... and the list goes on. Seems like you're into JS, so Node would likely be your choice. You have a few options, such as embedding your frontend application in views served by your backend, or keeping them separate, like a frontend talking to API endpoints using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

React-router, on the other hand, will allow you to move through the different screens of the single-page app you've created. It won't help you to make API endpoint calls.

So, as you can see, the two things aren't related even though they sound similar. In short, use react-router to navigate around your app, and use the Fetch API (or a component like [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) that has better compatibility for older browsers) to make your API endpoint requests.